# Randomize image in array in sprite kit swift.

Tags: swift

I was wondering if someone could show me how to make it so that I can spawn random image missiles. Right now I am using one image called "meteor", I have a few more images I would like to show and randomize. I know I need to put them in an array and create an arc for random. I have done it for sound but I'm not sure how to do it for images. This is my code so far.

```
var lastMissileAdded : NSTimeInterval = 0.0
let missileVelocity : CGFloat = 4.0

func addMissile() {
    // Initializing missile node
    var missile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "meteor")
    missile.setScale(0.44)

    // Adding SpriteKit physics body for collision detection
    missile.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: missile.size)
    missile.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(obstacleCategory)
    missile.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    missile.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = UInt32(shipCategory)
    missile.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    missile.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    missile.name = "missile"

    // Selecting random y position for missile
    var random : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(300))
    missile.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + 20, random - 20)
    self.addChild(missile)
}

func moveObstacle() {
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("missile", usingBlock: { (node, stop) -> Void in
        if let obstacle = node as? SKSpriteNode {
            obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: obstacle.position.x - self.missileVelocity, y: obstacle.position.y)
            if obstacle.position.x < 0 {
                obstacle.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is name them meteor0, meteor1 and meteor2 and use String Interpolation to create your node with your random image:

```
var missile = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "meteor\(arc4random_uniform(3))")
```